# Plant Nutrition

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

Alfie has two plants, A and B. He used some Vaseline to coat the top of the leaves on plant A and the underside of the leaves on plant B. He left the plants on the windowsill for a week and watered them regularly.

a) What do you expect happened to each plant?
Plant A: __________________________________
Plant B: __________________________________

b) Explain the result you have predicted for plant B

---

I think plant A would use a moderate amount of water and would use the least amount of water. I think plant B would use the least amounts because coating the lower surface causes the water loss similar to coating both surfaces (upper and lower).

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Is the plant a dicot or monocot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to think about the vaseline layer as a huge cuticle that our man "Alfie" just applied to the plants.

I think you have the right answer here. Just note that there is a typo in the first sentence of your thoughts. You missed a "B" in front of "plant". Took me a bit to understand.

Comment: Am I missing something? Plant B would have all stomata blocked.